Probing many test points on PCBs
I often have to trouble shoot one-off instruments. At the moment if I can't get a hook probe onto a pin I will scratch off some solder resist or use a pad to solder a flying wire to the board.
I'd like a fast and non-destructive way of holding probes on pads. Are there any flying probe tools which can be used to hold probes on pads for one-offs to work at a bench?
Most of the time I'm trying to catch serial data or analogue signals which I need a probe in place for a few days but don't know where immediately.
Similar questions have been posed on the forum this is specific to probing pads when a clip cant be used around a component leg.
E.g. like a spider board used for flash memory but cheaper and suitable for larger PCBs.  

thanks I've edited the question - I've read the question you linked and already own most of the solutions on there.

I have been using Sensepeek's PCBite probes for that purpose. They are designed exactly for the task you describe.
The probes have a flexible gooseneck with a magnetic base that attaches to a steel ground plane. There's a metal weight just above the tip of the probe. The probe is a spring-loaded pin that transfers the probe's weight onto the PCB without inducing undue mechanical shocks.
The probes shown below are good for say up to a few MHz. They got other probes that are like scope probes and work well all the way up to 500MHz. Very handy stuff, I got them all and are a satisfied customer.

The picture comes from Sensepeek's product page for SP10 probes.

these look great - thanks for the suggestion

Is there a way to swap out the board for another without fiddling with all the probes?

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany Not really. These are meant for interactive troubleshooting, for efficient manual probing. When board swaps are needed often, you'd need a bed of nails or flying probe or test connectors etc.

I think this is the best answer I found on the web - thanks very much
